# Floating WhatsApp button HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a floating WhatsApp button to my website by using Kevin Castro's Pen here: https://codepen.io/demoonkevin/pen/MvPEpV

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=12345&text=&source=&data=" class="whatsApp" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-whatsApp"></i></a>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* WhatsApp Button */

.whatsApp{
    position:fixed;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:40px;
    background-color:#25d366;
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    z-index:100;
}
.my-whatsApp{
    margin-top:16px;
}
```

However, there are a couple of issues:

1. It does not work on mobile?  The button doesn't show anywhere on the page...
2. The whatsapp logo is not white when I insert the code on my page (if you look at the pen above it has a green logo with a white whatsapp in the middle of the icon).

Comment: 1. It works on Chrome for Android when I try it. 2. The logo inherits the color of `a` elements.

Comment: you should add font awesome code in html and and inseart fonts in fonts folder

Answer (score 1):

To fix the color issue please add the following css to your **my-whatsApp** class because the a:visited property override the color

```
color: white;
```

In mobile, look like it work when i try from the browser

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that I had the same error.

When I copied the example, it didn't appear in mobile.

But then I just left it there for a month, came back and it worked.

So I guess it was a matter of refreshing the CSS file on the explorer when you make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change html font answer icon class in this case this not working new class code is :

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't see the whatsapp icon, include below code:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).